# Using igraph to plot nodes with coordinates in R

Tags: r, plot, igraph

I have a graph **main** and a meta-data data frame **meta**.

This is graph.

```
city <- data.frame(from = c("London", "Paris", "Beijing", "Berlin"), to = c("Beijing", "Berlin", "London", "Paris"))
main <- graph_from_data_frame(city)
```

And this is the data frame.

```
meta <- data.frame(name = c("Paris", "Hong Kong", "London", "Rome", "Berlin", "Beijing", "Madrid"), latitude = c(48.52, 22.26, 51.30, 41.54, 52.30, 39.9, 40.23), longitude = c(2.17, 114.12, 0.10, 12.29, 13.25, 116.3, 3.43))
```

As the **main** graph has only a part of cities in **meta**, I decide to assign the latitude and longitude from **meta** to **main** as vertex attributes.

```
V(main)$latitude <- meta$latitude[match(V(main)$from, meta$name)]
V(main)$longitude <- meta$longitude[match(V(main)$from, meta$name)]
```

After that, I try to layout the nodes with their latitude and longitude.

```
location <- matrix(c(V(main)$latitude, V(main)$longitude), ncol = 2)
plot(main, vertex.label = NA, vertex.size = 5, edge.width = 0.5, layout = location)
```

The problem is that I find these nodes are not in their right positions. I don't know where I made mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

This is a feature of how igraph plots.  If you look at the page `help(igraph.plotting)` you will find there:

```
rescale
Logical constant, whether to rescale the coordinates to the [-1,1]x[-1,1](x[-1,1])
  interval. This parameter is not implemented for tkplot. 
Defaults to TRUE, the layout will be rescaled.
```

So even though your layout (location) has the range [39.9,52.3]x[0.1-116.3], the default form of `plot`  will change plot to the area [-1,1]x[[-1,1].  You can use the `rescale` argument to suppress this behavior, but not that igraph will still use the plot region [-1,1]x[[-1,1] by default and your graph will simply be out of the plotting region. So you must also specify appropriate `xlim` and `ylim`.  But again,  by default,  igraph will force the region to have an aspect ratio of 1. Since the lat-longs in your data are somewhat imbalanced,   you probably also want to adjust the `asp` argument.  Putting this all together, I get

```
plot(main, vertex.label = NA, vertex.size = 5, edge.width = 0.5, 
    layout = location, rescale=FALSE, asp=0,
    xlim = range(V(main)$latitude), ylim = range(V(main)$longitude))
```

Now the coordinates of the vertices will match the lat-longs in your data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I simplified my original data to this version. May I ask what the `asp` argument for? Am I right when I try to set the vertex attributes from the `metadata` because I notice some cities are not in the `main` graph.

Comment: After I tried your way, those nodes are still in their former position, and the only change is the plotting gets bigger and scattered.

Comment: They may appear at similar places on the screen, but now the coordinates match you layout vector.   You can use `text` to display the lat-long

Comment: It seems correct when I swap the latitude with longitude, as I realise that in a coordinate system, the value of latitude is y-axis and the value of longitude is x-axis.